Botnet Detect Captcha Ajax Form Submit Always False

We are trying to integrate BotDetect Captcha 4.42 into our Umbraco site using the traditional API so we have a form with the Captcha on it that we are trying to post to the server using Ajax.
On the client we have:
 $.ajax({
 type: 'post',
     data: { 'CodeEntered': codeEntered, 'CaptchaInstance': capInstance },
     url: "/CaptchaSubmit",
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function (data) {

     // .etc...
 );

On the server we have:
var isValid = MvcCaptcha.Validate("CaptchaID", CodeEntered, CaptchaInstance);

Other than using the Simple API which doesn't seem right in our circumstance. Why would it work when the form is submitted by a normal post request, but fail by Ajax.
The validate method always returns false and about 1 in 30 attempts will return true as it should when the correct captcha code is entered.
We think its something to with the session, could anyone shed any more light on this please?
